# Unable to convert string into float

Tags: c++, arrays, string, visual-studio-2010

I write a code in which I scan character values and store them into an array. I type `'x'` to stop scanning characters. Now I put `'\0'` in the end of  array to convert array into string. Now I try to convert this string into float by using `std::stof`. Here is my code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>   
#include <string>     

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char str[100];;
    char rec;  
    char count=0;
    double n;
    std::string::size_type sz;  

    while(1)
    {
        scanf("%c",&rec);
        if(rec=='x')
        {
            str[count]='\0';
            printf("%s\n",str);
            sz = strlen(str);
            float value = std::stof (str,&sz);
            printf("%f",value);
        }
        else
        {
            str[count]=rec;
            count++;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

But this code is converting only first character into float value. For example , I give input:

```
1
2
3
.
4
x
```

My output is :-

```
1.000000
```

So, please tell me where is the problem

Comment: Using `std::cout` instead of `printf()` and `std::cin` instead of `scanf()` could simplify your code a lot.

Comment: But, printf() and scanf() are much faster than std::cout and std::cin.

Comment: @tourniquet_grab Do you think speed is a concern for this sort of a program ?

Comment: @Jagannath I'm not suggesting that the OP should stick to printf() and scanf(). I was merely pointing out an advantage of using them.

Comment: @tourniquet_grab That's out of context in my view.

Comment: @tabish Saifullah, Looks like you have `\n` in `str` . That's making `std::stof` to reject all the non-digit characters. Since you are writing this in Windows and hopefully using VS, you should be able to see that in the debugger. As suggested earlier, use `std::cin` and `std::cout` to simplify your code. Don't worry too much about performance for these kind of exercises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem arises because the input buffer is not cleared. When you press enter, the newline character `\n` is added to the input buffer. This can be fixed by adding `while(getchar()!='\n');` after calling `scanf`.

In the comments, πάντα ῥεῖ mentioned that using `std::cout` instead of `printf()` and `std::cin` instead of `scanf()` could simplify your code. It would also fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you really are entering a number with newline after each digit, your should be filtering these newlines out of your string. So use something like:

```
if (rec != '\n') {
  str[count]=rec;
  count++;
}
```

Instead of just:

```
{
  str[count]=rec;
  count++;
}
```